# Is there a more generic word for "space objects" (not counting human-made or massive objects)?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, science

Basically, objects like

- Asteroids
- Meteoroids
- Meteors
- Meteorites
- Comets
- Etc.

As stated in the title, this also doesn't count *human-made objects*, such as

- Space junk
- Satellites,
- Space stations,
- Rockets or shuttles
- Other crafts

Nor does it count what I'll call here *massive or unrelated objects* , such as stuff like

- Dwarf planets
- Planetesimals
- Proto-planets
- Moons
- Etc.

Here's a visual representation of what I mean that I whipped up in a minute:

[image: ]]

Comment: these are related but cannot be put under a common name.

Comment: Cosmic bodies? Space matter?

Comment: @TechieBee: Yes, they can. Everything can.

Comment: @Ricky: Too general. You can call objects that are **not** among these smaller bodies either *cosmic bodies* or *space matter*.

Comment: By the definitions you give in [your other question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281975/meteor-meteorite-is-to-meteoroid-as-a-b-is-to-asteroid), isn't it the case that "meteors" and "meteorites" are not in space? They don't really seem to fit.

Comment: "natural [small bodies](http://neo.jpl.nasa.gov/faq/#ast) in space." (or possibly, "natural small bodies orbiting the sun.") I doubt there's a single word; perhaps you'll be able to find an acronym that has been used, though. (NSBISes?)

Comment: @SarahofGaia check this out - http://www.sciencekids.co.nz/sciencefacts/space/cometasteroidmeteoroiddifferences.html

Comment: @TechieBee: What's the point of that link? Aside from sumelic's point at 22:41 UTC above, I'm was and am already aware of what the differences are between these terms.

Comment: @SarahofGaia the point is you cannot catagorize them in same level .Vaguely, if you still want to ignore the basic diffrences , you can call them "space rocks"

Comment: If there is no term in astronomic corpora that serves the purpose I seek, that would obviously be an answer to my question.

Comment: NASA calls them *minor objects*: http://history.nasa.gov/EP-177/ch2-4.html

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research, I found my answer: ***small Solar System bodies (SSSB)*** is the official [IAU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Astronomical_Union) term used for anything that is not a *planet*, *dwarf planet*, or *moon*.

In the article on the IAU site, ["Pluto and the Developing Landscape of Our Solar System"](https://www.iau.org/public/themes/pluto/), they define it as:

> a new IAU definition to encompass all objects orbiting the Sun that are too small (not sufficiently massive) to satisfy the definition of planet or dwarf planet.

For a more formal definition of the term, one can refer to the IAU's [Resolution B5](https://www.iau.org/static/resolutions/Resolution_GA26-5-6.pdf), made in 2006:

> (3) All other objects³,except satellites, orbiting the Sun shall be referred to collectively as "Small Solar System Bodies".
>
> `[Footnote 3]` "These currently include most of the Solar System asteroids, most Trans-Neptunian Objects (TNOs),comets, and other small bodies."

Comment: I take it back. This term doesn't work either. Per [@sumelic's comment above](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281746/is-there-a-more-generic-word-for-space-objects-not-counting-human-made-or-mas/281983#comment625844_281746), meteors and meteorites are not technically in space, so this term I don't think encompasses them. Although it would work if one takes out those two terms; alas, that's not what I'm doing.

Comment: How is "small solar system bodies" a (generic) **word**?