# Meteroid, or meteorite?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm making a programming example for a summer camp, and I'd like to get my terminology right.  This example is a game that student will make where they will fire missiles to defend earth from meteor[oid|ite]s (a bit like old-school asteroids).

My question then: are the students trying to protect the earth from meteoroids, or meteorites?

My understanding so far seems to suggest that missiles will be fired at a meteoroid, but if it reaches the ground it will become a meteorite.  I've seen a few definitions that all seem to agree with wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> A meteorite is a solid piece of debris from an object, such as a
>   comet, asteroid, or meteoroid, that originates in outer space and
>   survives its passage through the Earth's atmosphere **and** impact
>   with the Earth's surface or that of another planet

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25645/how-do-the-terms-comet-asteroid-meteoroid-meteor-and-meteorite-differ) on Physics Stack Exchange might offer you some additional insight.

Comment: Related question on ELU: [Meteor & Meteorite is to Meteoroid as A & B is to Asteroid?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281975)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the definitions right. The definition you left out is meteor, which is a meteoroid which is passing through the earth's atmosphere. As to what your students are trying to defend against by firing missiles, there is no point in firing a missile at a meteorite, which has already smashed down and creamed an area on the earth's surface -- or splashed down and caused a tsunami. Ideally, you want to deflect the meteoroid while it is still outside the Earth's atmosphere -- there is more time to deflect it.  Definitions paraphrased from [Sun.org](http://www.sun.org/encyclopedia/asteroids-meteoroids-meteors-meteorites-comets)

As to NASA's efforts to detect objects in space that could pose a hazard to Earth, see [The Asteroid Grand Challenge Digital Badging Effort](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/the-asteroid-grand-challenge-digital-badging-effort), but you may already know about that. As to firing missiles at meteors, which have entered the Earth's atmosphere, whether that is, at present technically easier than firing at meteoroids, that isn't an English question, but it is probably not. Your students are lucky to have such a project, and you will have fun.